# flutter Graphql Login

Tags: flutter, graphql, flutter-graphql

Future login() async
{
insert (
<String, dynamic> {
"username": useremail.text,
"password": password.text
}
);

```
          x = await  result.data.toString();
         if(x == null) {

           _showInSnackBar("somthing went wrong");


         }
         if(x != null)
         {
           _showInSnackBar("success");
         }

    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having? Try formatting your code a little better

Comment: Future login() async { insert ( <String, dynamic> { "username": useremail.text, "password": password.text } );

          x = await  result.data.toString();
         if(x == null) {

           _showInSnackBar("somthing went wrong");


         }
         if(x != null)
         {
           _showInSnackBar("success");
         }

    }   here is my code to function i have miss else with if condition await keyword in onpress() so ihave resolved it anyway thanks for reply brother @Gpack